# Order by two things in two different styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Theoretically what I want is this:
`:order => "column1 ASC, column2 DESC"`

But column1 is actually not a column in my case but an aggregated value:
`:order => relations.count`

How can I order by two columns when one of those is actually an aggregated value?

Btw: Counter-Cache is not an option (because it is outdated when I need it)

Answer (score 0):

```
:order => "COUNT(*), column2 DESC"
```

Comment: How could I select the relations count in that case?

Could I nest a SELECT in the COUNT? If so, how would I reference the current objects id (it is a scope btw)

Answer (score 0):

To order/group/etc by a calculated value, you have to specify it in the corresponding clause, in your case using a (possibly left) join too:

```
Something.select("somethings.*, COUNT(others.id)").
          joins("LEFT JOIN others ON others.something_id = somethings.id").
          group("somethings.*").
          order("COUNT(others.id), column2 DESC")
```

Comment: I am actually using a scope, so there is no select